# Regex match everything except multiple path patterns

Tags: regex, vue-router

Im trying to have a pattern that match all url paths except '/' or '/en' or '/en/' or '/es' or '/es/'

i tried some but it seems there is a particular way to make it work with vue router :

```
routes.push({
    name: 'test',
    path: '/(myregexpattern)',
    component: resolve(__dirname, 'test/b.vue'),
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a negative lookahead:

```
path : '/((?!en\/?$|es\/?$).+)'
```

Test it with [path-to-regexp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v1.7.0) which is what vue-router uses to parse the path.

example: https://jsfiddle.net/ellisdod/b3sdqjmL/

Might be easier to use a beforeEach to convert the path:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const routes = ['/','/en/','/es/']
  if ( !routes.some(x=> to.path===x) ) next('/mypath')
  else next()
})
```

Comment: this doesn't work in my case thats why i woulp prefer to use a regex